# Finding pattern in string using indexof

Tags: java, java-me

Can someone tell me why this is an infinte loop?

```
private void splitBody()    {
        bodyparts=new Vector();
        String body = "<br />testtestest<br />fefefefefefefefefef<br />qqqqqqqqqqqq";

        int previousIndex=0;
        while(body.indexOf("<br />",previousIndex)!=-1) {
            int index=body.indexOf("<br />",previousIndex);
            System.out.println(body.substring(previousIndex, index));
            bodyparts.addElement(body.substring(previousIndex, index));
            previousIndex=index;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because I think the answer I picked is a better solution. You increment the previousIndex with 1, while 6 is better because the pattern I'm looking for is 6 characaters long. So you don't need to check the next 5 characters like your solution advises. Does this make sence?

Comment: Not actually. By incrementing one, the pattern you are searching wont be found at the beginning of the string hence you're problem will be solved. To put it simply, the search will begin from "br />" and you're looking for "<br />" so it wont find it until the next occurance of "<br />". The solution you picked unnecessarily calculates the size of your pattern at each iteration.

Comment: yes it won't find the occurance again, but it will still check "br />", while when I just add 6, it doesn't and starts looking after. But actually I picked both of your answers; yours because just adding a nr s faster then calculating the size of br like you said & his because of adding 6 instead of 1 is a little bit faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indexOf operation return the starting position. If you want to move forward, increment the previousIndex like this.

```
  bodyparts=new Vector();
  String body = "<br />testtestest<br />fefefefefefefefefef<br />qqqqqqqqqqqq";

  int previousIndex=0;
  while(body.indexOf("<br />",previousIndex)!=-1) {
    int index=body.indexOf("<br />",previousIndex);
    System.out.println(body.substring(previousIndex, index));
    bodyparts.addElement(body.substring(previousIndex, index));
    previousIndex=index+("<br />".size());
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the last line to:

```
previousIndex = index + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't change your `body` string, so `indexOf` always returns an index different that `-1` since the substring is contained in `body`.

Add `body = body.substring(index);` at the end of the loop to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the issue:

```
previousIndex=index + 1;
```

Otherwise you'll always find the first occurance of the pattern.

Or - simplify the whole thing:

```
String[] parts = body.split("<br />");
```

Comment: This would be the best solution, but j2me works with a limited librairy (String doesn't has split method)